# Groovy: Delegate instance method to meta class

Tags: groovy

I'm findind a way easier to implement this kind of feature:

```
RESTClient client = new RESTClient("https://api.github.com", JSON)
class CoreApi {}
RESTClient.methods*.name.each { name ->
  if (! CoreApi.methods.contains(name)) {
    CoreApi.metaClass.static."$name" = {Object... args -> client."$name"(*args)}
  }
}
```

and then we can use `CoreApi.get(path: "/users/your-user")`

Is there any annotation available in groovy for implement this kind of behaviour? What's it called?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`@Delegate`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Delegate.html)

```
class CoreApi {
    @Delegate RESTClient client
}
```

But it doesn't work for static methods

> Static methods, synthetic methods or methods from the GroovyObject interface are not candidates for delegation